# Menu class errors - Java

Tags: java, methods

### UPDATE

the below errors have been solved however upon entering the author I am displayed with this message:

"

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

at manualLibrary.Library.add(Library.java:21)

at manualLibrary.Menu.main(Menu.java:25)
```

"
Is there any reason why this happens?

---

I am new to java and have been assigned some tasks to complete as follows:

[image]

I have been working through these tasks and have almost reached the end however I think my Menu class has errors present which prevents it from running. Here are the 4 different classes I am using:

Manual class:
http://pastebin.com/z31QBKf9

Console class:
http://pastebin.com/B4XFZESF

Library class:
http://pastebin.com/Gx25iDwA

Menu class:

```
package manualLibrary;

public class Menu 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // Initialise container
        //Manuals manuals = new Manuals();
        Library manuals = new Library();
        // declare boolean for while loop
        boolean finished = false;
        char option;
        // while loop
        while(! finished)
        {
            // ask option using menu choices
            option = Console.askOption("Select: A)dd, P)rint, Q)uit");
            // implement switch option
            switch (option)
            {
            // implement cases
            // add
            case 'A':
                Manual one = new Manual();
                one.ask("Enter manual details: ");
                manuals.addManual(one);
                break;
            // find 
            case 'F':
                manual = new Manual();
                String manualserialNumber = manual.askserialNumber("\nEnter the serial number for the manual: ");
                if ( manuals.find( manualserialNumber) != null)
                    System.out.println("Manual found is: " +manuals.find(manualserialNumber));
                else
                    System.out.println("Error: Manual not found! \n");
                break;
            // print
            case 'P':
                manuals.print("Stored manuals are: ");
                break;
            // quit menu case
            case 'Q':
                finished = true;
                System.out.println("End of application, goodbye!");
                break;
            // default case
            case '\0':
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid entry!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone has any ideas as to how I can fix the errors present please help, I have been working really hard on this and would love to get my code functioning.

### EDIT

Here are the errors eclipse throws up:

"

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 

The method askOption(String) is undefined for the type Console

The method ask() in the type Manual is not applicable for the arguments (String)

The method addManual(Manual) is undefined for the type Library

manual cannot be resolved to a variable

manual cannot be resolved

at manualLibrary.Menu.main(Menu.java:17)
```

"

Thank you!

Comment: *"I think my Menu class has errors present which prevents it from running"* Any error / exception messages? Please include them. Also, I recommend you debug your code (many IDEs have debugging tools such as step-by-step execution) to track where the problems are.

Comment: is this your homework? did you try something? what is wrong?

Comment: @Barranka Sorry, updated.

Comment: If you read the errors, you'd find out that you didn't define the methods.. and Manual declaration is not the the right place.

Comment: @user1071777 I read them but I am still unsure of how to fix the errors. What do you mean by Manual declaration not being in the right place, care to explain?

Comment: It says `The method askOption(String) is undefined for type Console`. You're using it here: `option = Console.askOption("Select: A)dd, P)rint, Q)uit");` but your Console class does not have `askOption` defined. It has an `askChar` which seems to be what you intended to use.

Comment: And you have `manual = new Manual();` where you're not declaring what type it is (ex. `Manual manual = new Manual();`)

Comment: And `addManual` is not defined, but there is an `add` method defined in your Library class which is what you probably mean to use.

Comment: And instead of `one.ask("Enter manual details: ");` You probably wanted 

`System.out.println("Enter manual details:");`
`one.ask();`

Comment: You've put work into this and obviously cannot finish it because you are missing some essential knowledge.In my opinion you really should not ask for help here just to have something that works but discuss whatever you're unsure about with the person that gave you the task. ;)

Comment: @user1071777 Wow, thank you very much for all your feedback, I have applied your changes and it runs well! Only one issue when I press enter after typing in the author I get an error stating: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException - at manualLibrary.Library.add(Library.java:21) - at manualLibrary.Menu.main(Menu.java:25)

Comment: Looks like you don't have a constructor for your Library class, so you're never initializing Library manuals variable. Probably you meant to write `public Library()` instead of `public void Manuals()` Either that or just call that method `manuals.Manuals()` (but that isn't really good form).

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty self-explanatory, but if you can't understand it, here goes...

1.) You try to call the method `Console.askOption()` with a `String` parameter, however no such method exists - you need to define it. However, it looks like you want `Console.askChar()`.

2.) You try to call the method `ask()` with a `String` parameter on your `Manual` instance, but the method you defined has no parameters. Use plain `one.ask();` instead, or it looks like here you want `one.print("Enter manual details: ");`.

3.) You try to assign an undeclared variable `manual` under the `case 'F':`, this should probably be `Manual manual = new Manual();` instead of `manual = new Manual();`.

4.) You try to call the method `addManual()` with a `Manual` parameter on your `Library` instance (no such method exists) - it looks like you wanted `manuals.add(one);`

5.) You try to call the method `print` with a `String` parameter on your `Library` instance (no such method exists) - it looks like you wanted `manuals.print();`

I think that's it.